# ORDER BY Has Error on Run Query With Case When

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM 
    (SELECT h.ID, h.Title 
     FROM table1 h
     LEFT JOIN table2 k ON h.ID = k.MediaID) a
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
       WHEN 1 = 1 THEN a.Title 
       ELSE a.ID
    END ASC
```

And my tables are like this:

table1

```
    id | title
    ---+------
     1 | aaaaa
     2 | bbbb
     3 | ccc
     4 | ddddd
```

table2

```
    id | mediaId
    ---+---------
     1 |    2
     2 |    2
     3 |    4
     4 |    1
```

When I run this query, I get this error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

What's wrong whit this code?

If I remove `Else` it works fine

Comment: move the DISTINCT into the derived table

Comment: @MartinSmith in that case both `ID` and `Title` should be in same type, e.g: both should be INT

Comment: No there is no such requirement that all columns have the same datatype to participate in `DISTINCT’

Comment: I run the code and it doesn't execute

Comment: Ah I see what you mean because the CASE expression will coerce both to the same dataype. Yes that is a requirement that they both be compatible types for the OPs approach to work, adding an alias as in your answer does nothing to help with either that or the original issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `case` expression returns a single value, with a single type.  You are mixing types and hence getting an error.  The rules of SQL says that strings are converted to numbers in this situation -- and that is where the error is happening.

The simple solution is two expressions:

`1 = 1` is rather arcane.  This would normally be something like:

```
order by (case when @var = 1 then a.title end),
         (case when @var = 2 then null else a.id end)
```

You could get rid of the error with an explicit conversion:

```
order by (case when 1 = 1 then a.title end),
               else cast(a.id as varchar(255)
          end)
```

However, this would not sort the data numerically for the second case.